# Docker CMD with environment variable while running node application

Tags: node.js, docker

I need to pass an environment variable to node like below.

```
RAZZLE_ENV=production node build/server.js
```

How I can achieve this with docker CMD command. My current config is like this:

```
CMD [ 'node', 'build/server.js' ]
```

I did change it to this:

```
CMD [ 'RAZZLE_ENV=production node', 'build/server.js' ]
```

But it does not work as expected and the container is not going to be created even.

UPDATE: the error is:

```
Cannot find module /app/RAZZLE_ENV=production node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dockerfile

```
# Use ARG so that it can be overridden at build time 
ARG ARG_RAZZLE_ENV=development

# Set environment variable based on ARG
ENV RAZZLE_ENV=$ARG_RAZZLE_ENV

CMD [ 'node', 'build/server.js' ]
```

Pass ARG during build:

```
docker build --build-arg ARG_RAZZLE_ENV=production . -t name:tag
```

Comment: this cannot set RAZZLE_ENV for runtime, need rebuild every time.